# Problems with Primefaces 2.2.1 file upload: flash buttons are sticked together

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, file-upload, primefaces

I'd like to upload multiple videos using Primefaces. I'm using `p:dataGrid` for this purpose:

```
<p:dataGrid var="videoBean" value="#{tutorialBean.videos}" columns="1" 
    effect="true">
    <p:column>
        <p:panel>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                <h:outputText value="Video" />
                <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{videoBean.handleVideoUpload}"
                    allowTypes="*.avi;*.mpg;" /> 

            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </p:column>
</p:dataGrid>
```

New videos are added by pressing 'Add video' button:

```
<p:commandButton value="Add video"
    action="#{tutorialBean.addNewVideo}" update="videos">
</p:commandButton>
```

`addNewVideo` method simply adds new empty `VideoBean` to the list.
And this is the result
[image: Video upload form]

Is this a bug or am I mistaken or misunderstanding something?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you set a different widget for each fileUpload?

Comment: You try to set a different widgetVar attribute for each fileUpload

Comment: Have this widgetVars to be generated in some way to be different?